# ScrollView prevents onPress event to work properly. How to solve this problem?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

The whole content is wrapped inside the scrollview. Because of this The onPress event needs two click to be activated.

```
<ScrollView>
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Popup     
      />
      <ImgsContainer />
      <Inputs/>
     //here is the problem
     <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={()=>{
       submitData() 
     } 
     }>
    <View style={styles.postBtn}><Text style= 
     {styles.btnText}>POST</Text></View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
     //////////////
    </View>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add enough code so that others can reproduce your issue, otherwise it's very hard to help. You can also take a look at [ask] and how to make a [mcve]